# ReSharper configuration in VS solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, configuration, resharper

Anyone have experience with adding a ReSharper profile to the VS2008 solution and share between developers - would like to mimmick the behavior of CodeStyle Enforcer and how it 'follows' the solution.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
/Jasper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in Options / Languages / Common / Code Style Sharing